# Algorithm for picking data so that their sum is a specified number, but prefer older data

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to implement a feature with following requirement but having hard time come up with a algorithm.

My data contains a positive integer value and a date. The numbers of data vary from 100 ~ 10,000.

```
-------------------------
 id | value |    date
-------------------------
 1  | 10    | 2015-01-01
 2  | 10    | 2015-01-02
 3  | 20    | 2015-01-02
  ....................
960 | 30    | 2015-09-10
961 | 15    | 2015-09-10
```

And a specified target value, says 5,000.

I would like to find a combination of the data, so their sum of the values equal to target, and they contains older data as much as possible. (The target number must match, it is okay to have a combination without using oldest data first)

Can anyone give me a direction how I can implement it ?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell whether the age of the data is more important than a close match to the target sum. For a first try, I would sort the data decreasing by age (or first by age, then by size such that larger items come first) an then in a greedy manner take elements in that sequence; skip an item if it does not fit.

Comment: Note that that's a variation of Subset-Sum (which is NP-Complete), with a restriction of "preferring older data"

Comment: @Codor > That's what I come up first, but both way has its defect. By age only may result no combination when it actually does. By large value first may cause smaller value never (or take a long time) been picked.

Comment: Lets ask it this way - what is better: exact amount with 5 items, or 1 off form the amount, with 4 of the same items and a fifth that is much older then the oe erased?

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov > The target number must match. I updated the question.

Comment: Is there "Optimal solution", for example, if you have `[(100,1.1.14), (33,1.1.15),(33,1.1.15),(44,1.1.15),(10,1.2.15)]` and `target=110` - would you prefer `[(100,1.1.14), (10,1.2.15)]` or `[(33,1.1.15),(33,1.1.15),(44,1.1.15)]`?

Comment: @amit > 1.1.14 means month.day.year ? in this case first combination is prefered

Comment: @RangiLin And what if it was (100,31.12.14)? What metric should choose?

Comment: @RangiLin I can think of a greedy approach that will guarantee local maximum, by "choosing" the oldest one at each choice point, but for some metrics (for example, total number of days ellapsed, ...) this is not optimal. It does guarantee oldest possible entry will be chosen

Comment: @amit > with (100, 31, 12, 14), still the first combination since it is the oldest data

Answer (score 2):

One approach based on Subset-Sum pseudo-polynomial solution could be :

First, sort the entries such that the oldest one is last, and the newest one is first. Then, generate the DP matrix based on the formulas:

```
D(i,0) = true
D(0,x) = false         x!= 0
D(i,x) = D(i-1,x) OR D(i-1, x-value[i])
```

This matrix is of size `(n+1) * (target+1)`.

Next, generate a solution by greedily choosing (from last to first) to take the element if it's possible:

```
t = target
i = n
sol = [] //empty list
while (t != 0):
    if D(i-1,t-value[i] == true):
        sol.append(i) //item i in the solution
        t = t - value[i]
    i = i-1 //either case
```

This guarantees:

1. Values of `sol` sums to the target
2. The oldest value which is in any feasible solution will be in `sol`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem can be interpreted as the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Note that this problem is `NP`-hard. It can be solved to optimality by [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) and admits an [FPTAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_approximation_scheme).

The problem can be modelled in the following way. The item profits and weights are the item's value (which means that the problem can be simplified to the `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem`). Let `C` denote the specified target value. Group the items by value; for value `v`, let keep only the `floor(C/v)` oldest items, where `floor` denotes rounding down. After the knapsack solver has generated a solution, replace the at most `floor(C/v)` items in the solution of value `v` (for each value `v`) with the oldest ones selected before.

Comment: That's not exactly true. Knapsack prefers higher value combination that are less than the max capacity, while it seems here - he wants exactly the max capacity. A counter example is `[(10,1.1.15), (10,1.2.15),  (30,1.3.15)]` with target value = 30

Comment: Well I see. The Knapsack problem might have an optimal solution which does not consume the total capacity, but the question asks for consuming the total capacity if possible; can this be fixed somehow?